# Powers of Irreducible Transition and Periodic Transition Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Suppose P is irreducible transition matrix with period d. How many communicating classes does P^k have and what is the period of each state?

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: Also, you can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Drawn some pictures of chains and have conjectured that if d devides k then P^k has d communicating classes all aperiodic and if d does not devide k then P^k is irreducible and aperiodic? How would I go about proving this?

Comment: ahah I'm stuck on the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but there is a theorem from the book [Gantmacher F.R. The Theory of Matrices, 1960, Vol. 2, P. 81, Theorem 9](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/gantmacher1.pdf) that might be of help:

If $A \geqslant 0$ is an irreducible matrix and some power $A^q$ of $A$ is reducible, then $A^q$ is completely reducible, i.e., $A^q$ can be represented by means of a permutation in the form $A^q = \operatorname{diag} \{ A_1, \dots, A_d \}$, where $A_1, \dots, A_d$ are irreducible matrices having one and the same maximal characteristic value. Here $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $q$ and $h$, where $h$ is the index of imprimitivity of $A$.